# Search with pagination how to make showing better

Tags: php, html

I have a simple search with simple pagination..I need to make the pagination better showing...like this 1.2.3.4.5...10.11 at all pages showing like this...can someone please help me with this...just showing less pages and better and not all...thanks

Here is the code:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
  <table width="599" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword
      <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $_GET["txtKeyword"];?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
if($_GET["txtKeyword"] != "")
    {
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("search");
    // Search By Name or Email
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE (title LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%' or year LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%')";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);


    $Per_Page = 2;   // Per Page

    $Page = $_GET["Page"];
    if(!$_GET["Page"])
    {
        $Page=1;
    }

    $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
    $Next_Page = $Page+1;

    $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
    if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
    {
        $Num_Pages =1;
    }
    else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
        $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
    }


    $strSQL .=" order  by ID DESC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
    $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);

    ?>
    <table width="600" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="91"> <div align="center">CustomerID </div></th>
        <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>
        <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>
        <th width="97"> <div align="center">CountryCode </div></th>
        <th width="59"> <div align="center">Budget </div></th>
        <th width="71"> <div align="center">Used </div></th>
      </tr>
    <?php
    while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $objResult["id"];?></div></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["title"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["synopsis"];?></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $objResult["CountryCode"];?></div></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $objResult["Budget"];?></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $objResult["Used"];?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <br>
    Total <?php echo $Num_Rows;?> Record : <?php echo $Num_Pages;?> Page :
    <?php
    if($Prev_Page)
    {
        echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page&txtKeyword=$_GET[txtKeyword]'><< Back</a> ";
    }

    for($i=1; $i<=$Num_Pages; $i++){
        if($i != $Page)
        {
            echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i&txtKeyword=$_GET[txtKeyword]'>$i</a> ]";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b> $i </b>";
        }
    }
    if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
    {
        echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page&txtKeyword=$_GET[txtKeyword]'>Next>></a> ";
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: Try this plugin for pagination and search http://datatables.net/ its fast and clean

Comment: On a side note you definitely don't want to be throwing `$_GET["txtKeyword"]` into your sql statement like that as is

Comment: And you don't want to `echo $_GET["txtKeyword"];` to the page without sanitizing it.